# C++ iterator mismatch error

Tags: c++11, vector

I am keeping track if instances of my class using std::vector to store pointers to all of the class objects.  I'm wrapping things up and want to remove the pointer in the destructor... but I am getting the following error:

> Brazos.cpp:15:89: error: cannot convert 'std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(const char*)'
>      instanceAddress.erase(std::remove(instanceAddress.begin(), instanceAddress.end(), this) instanceAddress.end());

it seems I may need to dereference the iterator... Here is my code:

```
std::vector<Brazos*> Brazos::instanceAddress;

Brazos::Brazos(Mano mano)
{
  instanceAddress.push_back(this);
  _mano = mano;
}

Brazos::~Brazos(void)
{
  instanceAddress.erase(std::remove(instanceAddress.begin(), instanceAddress.end(), this) instanceAddress.end());
}
```

Comment: strange syntax "instanceAddress.erase(  some-id  <space> some-id ); ?  My first guess is to add comma.  I am not sure.  If you post a standalone almost-compilable test-case in http://ideone.com/ or similar site, it will be easier to identify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma:

```
instanceAddress.erase(std::remove(instanceAddress.begin(), instanceAddress.end(), this), instanceAddress.end());
                                                                                       ^
```

Also, the error message refers to [`int std::remove(const char*)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove), so make sure you have `#include <algorithm>` for the correct `std::remove`.